# How to select a particular text in a span using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I would like to select a particular text from a span and highlight it using selenium webdriver and Java.

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<span>This is the sample text</span>.
</body>
</html>
```

Here I want to select only "sample" and highlight it. If I can able to select it, then the highlight part can be done using doubleclick action.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, can you please specify what language you are using to help answer your question easier. Can you also post some sample HTML markup where your text is located on the page so we can provide the way to identify the element.

Comment: Thanks. I need it in Java and the identification is not having any unique elements (like id or class) in it. I need to select it based on the given text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='5px solid red'", element);
```

This will put a red border around the element you want.

Comment: OP wants only **sample** Is that possible?

Comment: Good point, I misread the question. The only way I can think about doing it is splitting the  `element.Text` into a `string[]` and then pass that into the  `JavascriptExecutor` somehow.